# Wix installer is not removing files when uninstalling

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I was adding a new feature to my setup when I noticed something no longer worked.

I have an optional feature which is made up of components i.e. an activex installed in the application's folder and various dlls installed in another folder but when uninstalling the activex is the only file remaining in the application's folder and the filters are also remaining in their separate folder.

This used to uninstall both the ActiveX and the dlls just fine and deleted both these folders at the very end of the uninstall.

I've spent hours renaming all the guid for the ActiveX (re-generated a .wxs file with heat) and all the dlls as suggested on a similar article but to no avail!

I just don't get it, my app is removed, my windows service is stopped and removed, etc... but the activex and these dlls just won't get deleted!

I've noticed that the problematic files have their actions set to null. First in the feature part, the one that links the activex and dlls is null, yet the other 2 are fine!

```
MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: Doing action: InstallValidate
MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 04:01:07: KillAgentMonitor. Return value 1.
Action start 04:01:07: InstallValidate.
MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting 
MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its current value
is '86b17c5ff2f8de4d9424198f445cc8d1'.

MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: Feature: Feature2; Installed: Absent;
Request: Null;   Action: Null

MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: Feature: Feature3; Installed: Local;
Request: Absent;   Action: Absent

MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: Feature: Feature1; Installed:
Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent
```

Then the files that get removed:

```
MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: Component: CMP_File1;
Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent

MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:040]: Component: CMP_File2; 
Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent
```

Then the dll files:

```
MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:056]: Component: CMP_File53_DLL; Installed: 
Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null

MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:056]: Component: CMP_File54_DLL; Installed:
Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null

MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:056]: Component: CMP_File55_DLL; Installed: 
Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
```

As you can see the Actions are all Null??

And finally the activex:

```
MSI (s) (C4:C0) [04:01:07:056]: Component: CMP_MyActiveX_DLL; Installed: 
Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
```

Also Null!!

My activex is installed in c:\program files(x86)\mycompany\client and the dlls are installed in c:\windows\

I also read on some articles that one of the reasons this problem may occur is when the components might have left information in the registry but I've checked numerous specific and random GUID and none can be found.

There was a mention on another article that this could be due to the Ref count for dlls and may be that these were the the SharedDlls registry but again, not the case. I've checked and nothing in the registry.

I've also wipe my VM and rebuilt a fresh one but still no good.

I'm totally out of ideas as to what I can do next. Any other suggestions as to why the actions are null?

Should I be looking for something specific in my log?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I eventually figured out what caused this problem. It's not related to any of the suggested problems i.e. Invalid GUID, Higher version, ref count, being in the windows folder, etc...

One of my features is only displayed in the feature treeview if a command line parameter is provided i.e. INCLUDEFILTERS=1 as these are not provided to all our clients by default.

The code is:

```
<Feature Id="Feature2" Title="Filters" Level="10" Description="Select 
this option to install optional filters" TypicalDefault="install"
InstallDefault="local">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Feature2Components"/>
    <!--<Condition Level="0">
      <![CDATA[(INCLUDEFILTERS = 0)]]>
    </Condition>-->
</Feature>
```

By default INCLUDEFILTERS IS 0 unless provided via the command line and set to 1.

Now the problem seem to be related to this. When I'm carrying my test, I pass the INCLUDEFILTERS=1 which installs my activex and filter but I guess when you call the uninstall, it is not aware of that value and uses the default i.e. 0 and therefore does nothing.

Based on the above, I have to assume that when uninstalling it is somehow looking at the feature tree and it checks if it was selected or not.

Can I detect that the INCLUDEFILTERS was set to 1 at install time and reset the internal variable to 1 when uninstalling? Should I be using the 'Installed' within CDATA or is there an another way to achieve this?

I'll be honest, I'm not even sure if knowing this value will make a difference but right now I'm assuming it will.

I'll go ahead and try the 'Installed' condition in CDATA and I will update my answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Checked this list?    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2005/07/07/439810.aspx and also look for "disallowing uninstallation of {the guid} " for your guids.

Comment: HI, All the links are dead on this blog but I figure out the problem, well partially! I'll explain in Bob's reply.

Comment: The links might be stale, but certainly the commrnt there "The component has a condition which evaluates to false." seems to be somewhat relevant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the log for the GUID of each null-action component. Windows logs the reason it leaves a component. Files installed to the Windows and Windows system directories are generally permanent to mitigate [DLL hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). You can check for permanent components in your WiX authoring or your .msi's [Component table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Orca.

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested and it did not find anything in the uninstall log which got me thinking... After hours of scratching my head and going through my wix problem and trying various things, I then remembered that the activex and filters are part of a feature which is only enabled conditionally if a parameter is provided via the command line!  See updated answer (and new question!). Note that once I removed that condition, everything gets uninstalled as expected. Maybe you have a suggestion for the new question. Thanks.

Comment: Features need to be enabled during uninstall. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/05/16/make-sure-features-are-always-enabled-so-they-can-be-removed/.

Comment: Thanks for that Bob!! Only wish I had found that sooner! :). It would have saved me a lot of time. Is it better to use Remove or is it ok the way I mentioned it in my answer? Thanks.

Comment: "Installed" is ok but I'm not sure about "UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" too. I generally avoid features and use a chainer instead.

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed related to the condition I had against this specific feature. As mentioned, at installed time, I provide a command line parameter to include the ActiveX and filters. When uninstalling, it does not detect that this parameter was passed at install time, so to resolve this, I simply added another condition:

```
  <Feature Id="Feature2" Title="Filters" Level="10" Description="Select 
   this option to install optional filters" TypicalDefault="install"
   InstallDefault="local">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Feature2Components"/>
      <Condition Level="0">
        <![CDATA[(INCLUDEFILTERS = 0)]]>
      </Condition>
     <Condition Level="10">
      <![CDATA[(INCLUDEFILTERS = 1 OR (Installed AND NOT
                UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE))]]>
     </Condition>
  </Feature>
```

Shame it took hours to figure out such a simple line of code!! Hopefully this will help some else!